# Angular 2 Change Detection for deep neested object

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am using change detection in Angular 2 to watch for changed in a deep level array. Please see this plunker...

http://plnkr.co/edit/zcl9pT?p=preview

Is there anyway to do what I am doing without using changeDetectionStrategy? Its seems like overkill having to inject it in the parent component. I really only need it for the directive that loops through the list of selected filters.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html',
  providers: [MyService],
  pipes: [keyValueFilterPipe, ValuesPipe, AsyncPipe],
  directives: [MyDirective, MyDirective2],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.CheckAlways
})
export class HelloWorld {

    constructor(){}

  }
}
```

Comment: Seems it works with beta17 http://plnkr.co/edit/SwbjKn2M9NBBOYD29IML?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this bug is fixed in beta17, as @yurzui pointed out. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/SwbjKn2M9NBBOYD29IML?p=preview

Related PR: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/42231f5

It allows all legal programs in the dev mode.

> The checkNoChanges function compares only primitives types for equality, and deeply compares iterables. Other objects cannot cause checkNoChanges to throw. This means that the dev mode would never fail given a legal program, but may allow some illegal programs.

---

### Original Answer

The problem lies in your pipe's implementation. Every time `keyValueFilterPipe` returns a new JavaScript object, that is not the same as the last one returned by the same filter. Angular think this is a bug in your code and ceases to work.

You can see the error reported in console like `... has changed after it was checked`. Not only your directive stops to work, normal text-binding also breaks.

Angular2 in dev mode will try to figure out what is changed during its "dirty check". So if a developer mistakenly puts a cyclic call in template, Angular will report that.

This is a feature in Angular2. But it harms you.

The solution is easy. Either change the detection strategy, like you do. Or call `enableProd` to suppress the warning. Or implement `keyValueFilter` that always returns a fixed object(by `WeakMap` e.g.)

---

See also

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3040-i-have-a-fundamental-misunderstanding-of-change-detection-in-angular-2-beta-8.htm

And Angular's original issue, especially this comment

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5918#issuecomment-167422071

Comment: So I changed to 17, but the problem now is that I have the click the button to remote the item twice the first time, or set focus in the area of the directive. Why? http://plnkr.co/edit/7iUEja

Comment: Can you explain how I could get the keyValueFilter to return a fixed object?

Comment: Please update your example. I cannot know what you mean by remove twice because that button just alerts.

Comment: I think I got it working but do not like the implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/mwrD1W?p=preview I remove focus from the input when mouseenter of the other area where the buttons are.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell Using eventEmitter is a good choice in my eye :)